# How can I emit socket event from my clientside controller in daftmonks angular fullstack?

Tags: angularjs, sockets, angular-fullstack

I am using Daftmonk's angular-fullstack, and I want to send data through sockets TO the server. I found examples of how to receive from the server but not the other way around. The `socket` factory in the package doesn't seem to support any `emit` functions. So do I need to modify the socket service file to get that functionality or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to require the socket.js file in script .js

i have installed it via bower   and then in the controller create an instance of the socket like

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
```

this connects the socket to server and then you can emit the events  from the controller like

```
socket.emit("<event name>")
```

and listen that event on the server and you need an socket innstance attached to server   if not then npm install socket and then require it and then attach it to the app

the server side is:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);      
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);    
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){   console.log('a user connected');    })
server.listen(4000,function(){   console.log("The server running at port 4000"); });
```